# Vanishing viscosity solution is an entropy solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Actually, I have a problem in understanding a step in the proof of **Theorem $2$ of section $4$ of chapter $11$** of L.C. Evans' PDE.

I have understood the step: $\mathbb \phi (u^{\epsilon})_{t} + \mathbb \psi (u^\epsilon)_{x} = \epsilon D\phi(u^\epsilon)u^\epsilon_{xx}$.

But then how equality holds : $\epsilon \phi(u^\epsilon)_{xx} - \epsilon (D^{2} \phi(u^\epsilon)u^{\epsilon}_{x}).u^{\epsilon}_{x} = \epsilon D\phi(u^\epsilon)u^\epsilon_{xx} = \mathbb \phi (u^{\epsilon})_{t} + \mathbb \psi (u^\epsilon)_{x}$ ??

To be precise : how " $\epsilon \phi(u^\epsilon)_{xx} - \epsilon (D^{2} \phi(u^\epsilon)u^{\epsilon}_{x}).u^{\epsilon}_{x} = \epsilon D\phi(u^\epsilon)u^\epsilon_{xx} $ " ???

Please give me some explanation... I sense "Integration by Parts" somewhere...But couldn't get it... Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is application of product rule and chain rule:

\begin{align}
\phi(u^\varepsilon)_x&=D\phi(u^\varepsilon)\cdot u^\varepsilon_x,\\
\phi(u^\varepsilon)_{xx}&=(D\phi(u^\varepsilon)\cdot u^\varepsilon_x)_x\\
&=(D^2\phi(u^\varepsilon)\cdot u^\varepsilon_x)\cdot u^\varepsilon_x+D\phi(u^\varepsilon)\cdot u^\varepsilon_{xx}
\end{align}